# Shopify tags - Avoiding duplicate content

Tags: shopify

I used below code to prevent duplicate content. Everything works fine except ALL PRODUCT URL with tags(collections/all/red) are pointing to homepage as canonical.

```
{% if template contains 'collection' and current_tags %} <meta name="robots" content="noindex" /> <link rel="canonical" href="{{ shop.url }}{{ collection.url }}" /> {% else %} <link rel="canonical" href="{{ canonical_url }}" /> {% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be that `collections/all` sometimes behave in weird way. The best solution is to manually create collection `all`, with automatic rule like: `include all products with name not equal to "!@#"` or similar.

The `collections/all` exists on each shopify store, even if you cannot see this collection in admin panel. Sometimes it helps to overwrite this collection by creating another one with same handle